# Python rest client for formData type

Tags: python, rest, request

I am writing a rest client in pytho with request api

The rest server has rest api to upload file , it takes two parameters -

file     - the actual file  and its type is formData

fileName - the name of file in string and its type is also formData

I am using the below code

```
file = f = open('C:/tmp/test.txt', 'rb')
headers={'content-type':'multipart/form-data'}
r = requests.post(url+'/rest/2.0/process?'+file=f&fileName='test.txt'
```

but somehow its not working can anybody help where it needs correction

the corresponding rest server method is

```
@POST
@Consumes({"multipart/form-data"})
@TypeHint(Test.class)
public Response deployTestDefinition(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file, 
@FormDataParam("fileName") String fileName) {
```

my current request is like below :

```
    f = open('C:/tmp/Test.txt', 'rb')
    files = {'file' : ('Test.txt', f), 'fileName':'Test.txt'}
    headers={'content-type':'multipart/form-data'}
    r = requests.post(url+'/rest/2.0/process',files=files,headers=headers,cookies=token,verify=False)
```

but still not working status 400

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're not uploading the file properly. As per [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

```
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

You need to specify the `files` parameter and put the `f` instance in that dictionary.

Comment: Not working , I need to send the parameters as formData

Comment: I have added the corresponding server side method